# Вопрос начинающего java-программиста

Tags: java

Изучаю java программирование. Хотел поинтересоваться, есть такая строчка

```
 private static final String TAG = "myLogs";
```

Примерно понимаю, что создается переменная Tag типа стринг по умолчанию mylogs.

Что тут означают два слова:

**1. Final.

2. Static.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Слово `final` означает, что данной ссылке - TAG - ничего уже нельзя присвоить.

Слово `static` означает, что к данной ссылке можно ссылаться не через объект, а через класс. Т.е. чтобы вызвать эту ссылку, объект создавать не нужно - достаточно где-нибудь написать `MegaClass.Tag` (или как там у вас класс назван).

Comment: Спасибо! Доступно и понятно!

Comment: @duddeniska, тем не менее начинающему программисту не стоит пренебрегать литературой по Java.

Answer (score -1):

Означает, что это НЕ переменная, и она доступна без создания экземпляра класса.

Comment: Добавлю еще, что статические переменные как бы "глобальные" переменные. В частности удобно использовать для подсчета открытых окон одного типа, например.

Comment: > что это НЕ переменная

скажите ещё, что присвоить значения такой переменной нельзя. (вообще то можно, но только в одном случае - если это конструктор и переменная ещё не была инициализирована).